# "Encrypted Home Directory" feature in 14.04

Tags: encryption

Good day to all,

I installed OpenCV 2.4.10 to my Ubuntu 14.04. I followed all the steps in installing OpenCV according to Sysads Gazette. The last step after installing OpenCV requires to reboot the machine, but after rebooting I got this message and I cannot continue further (it seems that the system hanged or something):

```
 The disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present.
 Continue to wait, Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

***I did a little research, and I found out that these might be the two reasons for this to happen***:

```
1) It has something to do with the Swap partition

2) It has something to do with the option during the installation of Ubuntu 
"Encrypt your home directory in case your computer is stolen. 
The folder contents will be decrypted automatically when you log in.. etc.etc...".
```

I'm guessing that it is because of the second reason, because I did select to encrypt during my installation of Ubuntu 14.04.

I found a solution in order to remove the encryption which is

```
 1) edit the fstab entry for cryptswap1 to include the option 'noauto'

 sudo gedit /etc/fstab


 2) then change the line that looks like

 /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0

 to

 /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw noauto 0 0
```

My question is, how do I access the terminal in order to do this solution knowing that I would be editing something using gedit. Or is there any other way of solving this other than the solution that I have found?

I tried system recovery, but it does not let me edit the code.

Source for installing OpenCV 2.4.10 in Ubuntu 14.04:

```
http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/05/install-opencv-2-4-9-ubuntu-14-04-13-10/
```

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you file a bug report against opencv. I do not understand why a reboot would be required to install opencv or why encryption is the problem or even if this has to do anything with opencv

Answer (score 0):

You want to edit `/etc/fstab` using terminal, you can do it using `vi` editor and you cannot use gedit in cli mode.

Execute following command to edit the `/etc/fstab` file.

```
vi /etc/fstab
```

Then move the cursor to the point where you want to insert the data,i.e. between sw and 0, press Esc button from your keyboard and then press `i` to goto insert mode, write noauto

When you are done editing , press Esc button again and then press `:wq` to write changes.

[See manpages for more info (Click here)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/nvi.1.html)